# Jquery Post - Php Get Problem

Tags: php, jquery, post, get

i have problem at jquery post, php get. but i don't get any value. i'm everytime get error. so what i do wrong? there are the codes

it's jquery post:

```
$.post("a.php", { imagetext: $("textarea").val() } );
```

it's php get:

```
echo $_GET["imagetext"];
```

*p.s:i'm beginner at php.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are sending a `POST` request, you need to use `$_POST["imagetext"];` in your PHP. Alternatively, you could change it to a `GET` request with jQuery `$.get`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `$_POST["imagetext"]` in PHP because you are posting with jQuery. What you are doing is acting like the request was made with GET, but `$.post(...)` will make a POST request.

Answer (score 1):

The reason echo `$_GET["iamgetext"];` doesnt print out anything is because it is not set. At least not by your ajax call.

You have 2 options.

1. Use `echo $_POST["imagetext"];`
2. use `$.get()` for your ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.post("a.php", { imagetext: $("textarea").val() } );
echo $_POST["imagetext"];
```

You are using the wrong global var, should be like above.